# Why must I immediately invoke an immediately invoked function expression?

Tags: javascript, module

If I have:

```
var calc = function(){
  return {
    adder: function(x,y){return x+y;}
  }
};
calc();
calc.adder(4,5);
```

calc.adder is undefined. However, if I immediately invoke calc as

```
var calc = function(){
  return {
    adder: function(x,y){return x+y;}
  }
}();
calc.adder(4,5);
```

things work as expected. Why does the first example fail?

Comment: Because `calc()` returns a new function and you didn't assign that new function to anything so it was lost and is not available for subsequent method calls.  You could do `calc().adder(...)`.  Or you could do `var c = calc(); c.adder(...)`.

Comment: Just to be pedantic, if you don't invoke it immediately, then it's not an "immediately invoked function expression".  It's just a function expression.

Comment: Interesting Andrew - so if it's written the first way, you must always call it with calc().adder(4,5) yet with the second way you can call it with calc.adder(4,5). So, additional question, ha

Comment: Yes Pointy. I'm wondering why they differ beyond the pedantic. The second one allows me to call calc.adder, while the first does not.

Comment: This question is, somehow, weird!

Comment: @Pointy I'm not sure I'd call that pedantic, it's kind of the definition.

Comment: The second one assigns `calc` to be the result of executing that first outer fucntion.  The first one assigns calc to be the outer function.  There's certainly a difference between those two so of course you have to use `calc` differently in the two scenarios.  Is that not obvious?

Comment: @Harold `calc.adder()` only works if "adder" is a property of "calc"; it isn't.

Comment: No jfriend it's not obvious to me. I'm too stupid. That's why I came to people like you for help.

Comment: You've got a function that returns an object. If you don't **call** the function, you can't get the object back.

Comment: But Pointy, I call the function in both places. Just, in the first example, I call the function one line earlier than the second.

Comment: @jfriend00 I would have welcomed that as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### First code set

`calc()` is a function that returns an object that contains a function called `adder()`.  So this will work.

```
var calc = function(){
    return {
        adder: function(x,y){return x+y;}
    }
};

var cal = calc();
cal.adder(4,5);
```

The line of code

```
calc();
```

Stores the returned object in no variable, so you can't use the object.

### Second code set

The second example you posted is essentially the same thing.  The calc variable is no longer a function, it is the object that the un-named function returns when you execute it with the `()`;